# Complex Grouping of rows based on row value sequences in Spark Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a set of rows, where each event row is uniquely identified by **"EventId"**. A set of events belong to a group, identified by **"GroupId"**.

`"BeginEndMarker" = 1` is the possible start event.
`"BeginEndMarker" = 5` is the possible end event.
`"BeginEndMarker"= -1` are the intermdiate events.

**Example:**

```
val df= Seq(
("GroupId1", "WF1", 1, "01-01-2023"),
("GroupId1", "WF2", -1, "01-02-2023"),
("GroupId1", "WF3", -1, "01-03-2023"),
("GroupId1", "WF4", 5, "01-04-2023"),
("GroupId1", "WF5", 5, "01-05-2023"),
("GroupId1", "WF6", 1, "01-06-2023"),
("GroupId1", "WF7", 1, "01-06-2023"),
("GroupId1", "WF8", -1, "01-07-2023"),
("GroupId1", "WF9", 5, "01-08-2023"),
("GroupId1", "WF10", 1, "01-09-2023"),
("GroupId1", "WF11", -1, "01-10-2023"),
).toDF("GroupId", "EventId","BeginEndMarker","Time")
df.show

+--------+-------+--------------+----------+
| GroupId|EventId|BeginEndMarker|      Time|
+--------+-------+--------------+----------+
|GroupId1|    WF1|             1|01-01-2023|
|GroupId1|    WF2|            -1|01-02-2023|
|GroupId1|    WF3|            -1|01-03-2023|
|GroupId1|    WF4|             5|01-04-2023|
|GroupId1|    WF5|             5|01-05-2023|
|GroupId1|    WF6|             1|01-06-2023|
|GroupId1|    WF7|             1|01-06-2023|
|GroupId1|    WF8|            -1|01-07-2023|
|GroupId1|    WF9|             5|01-08-2023|
|GroupId1|   WF10|             1|01-09-2023|
|GroupId1|   WF11|            -1|01-10-2023|
+--------+-------+--------------+----------+
```

These event rows need to be subgrouped, such that each subgroup starts with first occurence of "BeginEndMarker"=1 and end of that subgroup is the last "BeginEndMarker"=5 and next event being "BeginEndMarker"=1.
A subgroup might have no event with "BeginEndMarker" = 5, as it could be an incomplete subgroup.

The expected result should be :

```
+--------+-------+--------------+----------+--------+
| GroupId|EventId|BeginEndMarker|      Time|Subgroup|
+--------+-------+--------------+----------+--------+
|GroupId1|    WF1|             1|01-01-2023|     SG1|
|GroupId1|    WF2|            -1|01-02-2023|     SG1|
|GroupId1|    WF3|            -1|01-03-2023|     SG1|
|GroupId1|    WF4|             5|01-04-2023|     SG1|
|GroupId1|    WF5|             5|01-05-2023|     SG1|
|GroupId1|    WF6|             1|01-06-2023|     SG2|
|GroupId1|    WF7|             1|01-06-2023|     SG2|
|GroupId1|    WF8|            -1|01-07-2023|     SG2|
|GroupId1|    WF9|             5|01-08-2023|     SG2|
|GroupId1|   WF10|             1|01-09-2023|     SG3|
|GroupId1|   WF11|            -1|01-10-2023|     SG3|
+--------+-------+--------------+----------+--------+
```

Any idea how this can be implemented in Spark without using UDF?

Comment: What approach did you try on this question? I believe window function could tackle it.

Comment: Yes, windowing would be an option. So far I tried.

val w = Window.partitionBy("GroupId").orderBy("Time")
val df1 = df.withColumn("NextVal", lead("BeginEndMarker", 1).over(w))
df1.show

val df2 = df1.withColumn("EndMarker", when((col("BeginEndMarker") === 5 && col("NextVal") === 1) || col("NextVal").isNull, 1).otherwise(0))
df2.show

I got the correct EndMarker. Now I need to group them like Sg1, Sg2, Sg3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With hints from @RvdV, I tweaked the code and got the required solution:

Thank you! With some minor modifications as below (scala code), the expected solution is obtained!

```
val w = Window.partitionBy("GroupId").orderBy("Time")
val df1 = df.withColumn("NextVal", lead("BeginEndMarker", 1).over(w))
val df2 = df1.withColumn("EndMarker", when((col("BeginEndMarker") === 5 && col("NextVal") === 1) || col("NextVal").isNull, 1).otherwise(0))
val w_events = Window.partitionBy("GroupId").orderBy("EventId")
val w_cumsum = w_events.rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, -1)
df2
  .withColumn("group_number", sum("EndMarker").over(w_cumsum)+1)
  .withColumn("group_number_new", when(col("group_number").isNull, lead("group_number", 1).over(w)).otherwise(col("group_number")))
  .withColumn("Subgroup", concat(lit("SG"), col("group_number_new")))
  .show
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a fun little puzzle. I think it can be solved with window functions as the comment sugggest.
So, what I derive from your examples:

- 1 are start events, 5 ends. -1 can be ignored for determining the grouping.
- The values need to be ordered by EventId to interpret the order of the BeginMarkers
- Start/End events can be more than one, in that case use the first start event as the start of a new group.
- The thing to focus on is transitions from stae 5 to 1, since that is the trigger to create a new group (with the exception of the first group)

I think the solution looks something like this:

```html
from pyspark.sql import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

w_events = Window.partitionBy("GroupId).orderBy("EventId")
w_cumsum = w_events.rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0)

grouped_events = (events
  .withColumn("is_new_event_start", f.when(f.col("BeginEndMarker") == 1 && f.lag("BeginEndMarker", 1).over(w_events) == 5, 1).otherwise(0))
  .withColumn("group_number", f.sum("is_new_event_start").over(w_cumsum))
  .withColumn("Subgroup", f.concat(f.lit("SG"), f.col("group_number"))
)
```

I didn't test the code above, but something like this should work. You make a window to indicate the ordering, and use the `lag` function to detect transitions from state 5 to 1. You create a new column to indicate with a "1" where a new group starts. Then you make a cumulative sum over that newly created column, which will increment the subgroup id by 1 every time there is a new event.

P.S. The code probably won't work for the first row since you don't have an end before the first start. You could solve this by giving the [lag function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.lag.html#pyspark.sql.functions.lag) a default value of 5 perhaps